# Vue: Add a new dynamic form input when a value is added to the previous input

Tags: vue.js

so I need to have a form input create whenever the user adds a value to the previous input. I've found some great questions about how to create dynamic forms and also how to watch form inputs to call a function but I don't know how to combine the two and make them work together.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#form',
  data: {
    items: [],
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.items.push({
        value: ''
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="form">
  <input v-for="item in items" v-model="item.value">
  <button @click="addItem">add</button> {{items}}
</div>
```

So currently I can make this work by adding a button to add the new input but the input doesn't show until after you click the button. I tried `v-for="item in items + 1"` but that cause crazy unexpected results and after I thought about it I realized why that couldn't work. I would really like to have an input box on load and if the user adds any value to that box a new one will be created.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I actually just figured it out on my own :p I need to run the function on mount and then use v-on:change.once to run the function.

Now I just need to figure out how to remove the input box when it is empty.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#form',
  data: {
    items: [],
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.items.push({
        value: ''
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.addItem()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="form">
  <input v-for="item in items" v-model="item.value" @change.once="addItem()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Initializing your `items` with `[{ value: '' }]` works:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#form',
  data: {
    items: [{
        value: ''
    }],
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.items.push({
        value: ''
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="form">
  <input v-for="item in items" v-model="item.value">
  <button @click="addItem">add</button> {{items}}
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I tried something similar `value: [''] ` but the value wasn't editable that way. I actually solved the issue above but yours is cleaner.

Comment: Yeah. I think the logic is the same; You answer adds the object when the component is `mounted` and mine adds the object as initial value.